# Escrow outputs show incorrect destination addresses in Blockchain.info

Tags: blockchain.info, multi-signature, escrow

I'm interested in the following multisig transaction

```
3a0c283c8574205c2cc95cea0e603bfff9087af2ab0360ebd2e98740a3193a18
```

If I query bitcoind for information about it using the following command

```
 $> bitcoind getrawtransaction 3a0c283c8574205c2cc95cea0e603bfff9087af2ab0360ebd2e98740a3193a18 1
```

then I see that two addresses are involved in its outputs, namely

```
1HT7xU2Ngenf7D4yocz2SAcnNLW7rK8d4E and 1GcFhAQGFZVDAr4jiR2tKwisHcgNUjhGNC.
```

However, if I look up this same transaction hash on blockchain.info, located here

https://blockchain.info/tx/3a0c283c8574205c2cc95cea0e603bfff9087af2ab0360ebd2e98740a3193a18

Suddenly there are three addresses involved in the outputs, namely

```
17YnWEp2vjT1wEgALyy2BApY8CAMr78M7o and 1ADwCr1Ary8KX2i41MhQKL4TgkTRV6p14G and 1GcFhAQGFZVDAr4jiR2tKwisHcgNUjhGNC.
```

Where did the 1HT7xU2Ngenf7D4yocz2SAcnNLW7rK8d4E address go, and what are these two new addresses? I have noticed this for most of blockchain.info's multisig transactions, can they not properly parse them?

EDIT: Here it the output I get when I run

```
bitcoind getrawtransaction 3a0c283c8574205c2cc95cea0e603bfff9087af2ab0360ebd2e98740a3193a18 1


{
"hex" : "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",
"txid" : "3a0c283c8574205c2cc95cea0e603bfff9087af2ab0360ebd2e98740a3193a18",
"version" : 1,
"locktime" : 0,
"vin" : [
    {
        "txid" : "be041dbcf26c03e44853b48585c4a4ffe6a29a8bf33e6fc341cca2f3a256850a",
        "vout" : 0,
        "scriptSig" : {
            "asm" : "3045022100c177dca01b7208feb04497d8948e832af7b12b5b74d1ff07db4a40c3782250b602205211a54941fe741e7220d90eda8ec75bb337b7ad7d8a9b0c40c614b2639cc37701 0336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e",
            "hex" : "483045022100c177dca01b7208feb04497d8948e832af7b12b5b74d1ff07db4a40c3782250b602205211a54941fe741e7220d90eda8ec75bb337b7ad7d8a9b0c40c614b2639cc37701210336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e"
        },
        "sequence" : 4294967295
    },
    {
        "txid" : "0fa11650c73cd2522c7ecf2f6d7363d26d23c25cdc02630433ab588f4063d6ea",
        "vout" : 0,
        "scriptSig" : {
            "asm" : "3045022100dc123d788fdc315f71df992a09d2f31237aadee954f0c7ed9ebf6676fde2806c022016f32f64109b92895ad35d6da1ad050fd1313e40092e51e222eed8cb9803277601 0336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e",
            "hex" : "483045022100dc123d788fdc315f71df992a09d2f31237aadee954f0c7ed9ebf6676fde2806c022016f32f64109b92895ad35d6da1ad050fd1313e40092e51e222eed8cb9803277601210336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e"
        },
        "sequence" : 4294967295
    },
    {
        "txid" : "0be4e71854504e99b491424826722e65d3bc369f7687ccda72b80673da7226ab",
        "vout" : 0,
        "scriptSig" : {
            "asm" : "3046022100f4eec08e55254dd3f1803c88b47bf4d0527af7b6d54d3c28300175ab2cf4cde6022100ea58b455294ca78bcca651b4031a0049c4b359834d6face1d87fe39c6ac9914e01 0336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e",
            "hex" : "493046022100f4eec08e55254dd3f1803c88b47bf4d0527af7b6d54d3c28300175ab2cf4cde6022100ea58b455294ca78bcca651b4031a0049c4b359834d6face1d87fe39c6ac9914e01210336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e"
        },
        "sequence" : 4294967295
    },
    {
        "txid" : "fcacf93adb64540df1b730f3c9706ac9c3c8a86d7a14ce8752eb4c1a6eb7a6d9",
        "vout" : 1,
        "scriptSig" : {
            "asm" : "3046022100ccb7797be4de4e6b890869fed98d2d66bfeb787fc3a10d9da4735688d2c1b3230221009dcff82c291fdb90ac15325a02073e52686addf8b0c25eb28dc8b410e8c3282901 0336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e",
            "hex" : "493046022100ccb7797be4de4e6b890869fed98d2d66bfeb787fc3a10d9da4735688d2c1b3230221009dcff82c291fdb90ac15325a02073e52686addf8b0c25eb28dc8b410e8c3282901210336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e"
        },
        "sequence" : 4294967295
    }
],
"vout" : [
    {
        "value" : 0.00007800,
        "n" : 0,
        "scriptPubKey" : {
            "asm" : "1 0336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e 20434e5452505254590000000a00000000d806c1d5000000039dc87f4000000000 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
            "hex" : "51210336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e2120434e5452505254590000000a00000000d806c1d5000000039dc87f400000000052ae",
            "reqSigs" : 1,
            "type" : "multisig",
            "addresses" : [
                "1GcFhAQGFZVDAr4jiR2tKwisHcgNUjhGNC",
                "1HT7xU2Ngenf7D4yocz2SAcnNLW7rK8d4E"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "value" : 0.00007800,
        "n" : 1,
        "scriptPubKey" : {
            "asm" : "1 0336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e 1600000001000000005f5e100003e8000000000000000000000000000000000000 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
            "hex" : "51210336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e211600000001000000005f5e100003e800000000000000000000000000000000000052ae",
            "reqSigs" : 1,
            "type" : "multisig",
            "addresses" : [
                "1GcFhAQGFZVDAr4jiR2tKwisHcgNUjhGNC",
                "1HT7xU2Ngenf7D4yocz2SAcnNLW7rK8d4E"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "value" : 0.00732450,
        "n" : 2,
        "scriptPubKey" : {
            "asm" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 ab34b5c668a8ed435ede840b6f40e3eddb455c62 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
            "hex" : "76a914ab34b5c668a8ed435ede840b6f40e3eddb455c6288ac",
            "reqSigs" : 1,
            "type" : "pubkeyhash",
            "addresses" : [
                "1GcFhAQGFZVDAr4jiR2tKwisHcgNUjhGNC"
            ]
        }
    }
],
"blockhash" : "000000000000000010fd711cae1e3069a90e657664872ff019f3544fe78f9284",
"confirmations" : 1166,
"time" : 1404255586,
"blocktime" : 1404255586
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Lets look carefully on 
https://blockchain.info/tx/3a0c283c8574205c2cc95cea0e603bfff9087af2ab0360ebd2e98740a3193a18

output #0 is msig 1-of-2 to { 0336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e, 20434e5452505254590000000a00000000d806c1d5000000039dc87f4000000000 }

the first long number [0336..641e] is public key of address 1GcFhAQGFZVDAr4jiR2tKwisHcgNUjhGNC

the second [2043..0000] is not a public address at all. bc.i hashes it to an address 17YnWEp2vjT1wEgALyy2BApY8CAMr78M7o

the address 1HT7xU2Ngenf7D4yocz2SAcnNLW7rK8d4E is hash160 ( 0000...0000 ) - invalid public key

seems to me that the client converts all invalid public keys to address 1HT7xU2Ngenf7D4yocz2SAcnNLW7rK8d4E

look here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=8728.msg202068#msg202068

and here: http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/issues/detail?id=264

Comment: Ah that's good to know, thanks for pointing that out. I'm surprised they haven't fixed that to return some sentinel value that draws attention to the fact that they're using an invalid address.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it would have been easier if you pasted the `bitcoind getrawtransaction` result, which is the following:

```
{
"hex" : "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",
"txid" : "3a0c283c8574205c2cc95cea0e603bfff9087af2ab0360ebd2e98740a3193a18",
"version" : 1,
"locktime" : 0,
"vin" : [
    {
        "txid" : "be041dbcf26c03e44853b48585c4a4ffe6a29a8bf33e6fc341cca2f3a256850a",
        "vout" : 0,
        "scriptSig" : {
            "asm" : "3045022100c177dca01b7208feb04497d8948e832af7b12b5b74d1ff07db4a40c3782250b602205211a54941fe741e7220d90eda8ec75bb337b7ad7d8a9b0c40c614b2639cc37701 0336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e",
            "hex" : "483045022100c177dca01b7208feb04497d8948e832af7b12b5b74d1ff07db4a40c3782250b602205211a54941fe741e7220d90eda8ec75bb337b7ad7d8a9b0c40c614b2639cc37701210336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e"
        },
        "sequence" : 4294967295
    },
    {
        "txid" : "0fa11650c73cd2522c7ecf2f6d7363d26d23c25cdc02630433ab588f4063d6ea",
        "vout" : 0,
        "scriptSig" : {
            "asm" : "3045022100dc123d788fdc315f71df992a09d2f31237aadee954f0c7ed9ebf6676fde2806c022016f32f64109b92895ad35d6da1ad050fd1313e40092e51e222eed8cb9803277601 0336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e",
            "hex" : "483045022100dc123d788fdc315f71df992a09d2f31237aadee954f0c7ed9ebf6676fde2806c022016f32f64109b92895ad35d6da1ad050fd1313e40092e51e222eed8cb9803277601210336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e"
        },
        "sequence" : 4294967295
    },
    {
        "txid" : "0be4e71854504e99b491424826722e65d3bc369f7687ccda72b80673da7226ab",
        "vout" : 0,
        "scriptSig" : {
            "asm" : "3046022100f4eec08e55254dd3f1803c88b47bf4d0527af7b6d54d3c28300175ab2cf4cde6022100ea58b455294ca78bcca651b4031a0049c4b359834d6face1d87fe39c6ac9914e01 0336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e",
            "hex" : "493046022100f4eec08e55254dd3f1803c88b47bf4d0527af7b6d54d3c28300175ab2cf4cde6022100ea58b455294ca78bcca651b4031a0049c4b359834d6face1d87fe39c6ac9914e01210336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e"
        },
        "sequence" : 4294967295
    },
    {
        "txid" : "fcacf93adb64540df1b730f3c9706ac9c3c8a86d7a14ce8752eb4c1a6eb7a6d9",
        "vout" : 1,
        "scriptSig" : {
            "asm" : "3046022100ccb7797be4de4e6b890869fed98d2d66bfeb787fc3a10d9da4735688d2c1b3230221009dcff82c291fdb90ac15325a02073e52686addf8b0c25eb28dc8b410e8c3282901 0336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e",
            "hex" : "493046022100ccb7797be4de4e6b890869fed98d2d66bfeb787fc3a10d9da4735688d2c1b3230221009dcff82c291fdb90ac15325a02073e52686addf8b0c25eb28dc8b410e8c3282901210336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e"
        },
        "sequence" : 4294967295
    }
],
"vout" : [
    {
        "value" : 0.00007800,
        "n" : 0,
        "scriptPubKey" : {
            "asm" : "1 0336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e 20434e5452505254590000000a00000000d806c1d5000000039dc87f4000000000 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
            "hex" : "51210336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e2120434e5452505254590000000a00000000d806c1d5000000039dc87f400000000052ae",
            "reqSigs" : 1,
            "type" : "multisig",
            "addresses" : [
                "1GcFhAQGFZVDAr4jiR2tKwisHcgNUjhGNC",
                "17YnWEp2vjT1wEgALyy2BApY8CAMr78M7o"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "value" : 0.00007800,
        "n" : 1,
        "scriptPubKey" : {
            "asm" : "1 0336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e 1600000001000000005f5e100003e8000000000000000000000000000000000000 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
            "hex" : "51210336aa4df526a776e2b72512bb65d8ad5c661360cc1de2ffe460b618c0bba6641e211600000001000000005f5e100003e800000000000000000000000000000000000052ae",
            "reqSigs" : 1,
            "type" : "multisig",
            "addresses" : [
                "1GcFhAQGFZVDAr4jiR2tKwisHcgNUjhGNC",
                "1ADwCr1Ary8KX2i41MhQKL4TgkTRV6p14G"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "value" : 0.00732450,
        "n" : 2,
        "scriptPubKey" : {
            "asm" : "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 ab34b5c668a8ed435ede840b6f40e3eddb455c62 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
            "hex" : "76a914ab34b5c668a8ed435ede840b6f40e3eddb455c6288ac",
            "reqSigs" : 1,
            "type" : "pubkeyhash",
            "addresses" : [
                "1GcFhAQGFZVDAr4jiR2tKwisHcgNUjhGNC"
            ]
        }
    }
],
"blockhash" : "000000000000000010fd711cae1e3069a90e657664872ff019f3544fe78f9284",
"confirmations" : 1100,
"time" : 1404255586,
"blocktime" : 1404255586
```

}

On the above output there are three outputs which they seem to agree with blockchain.info.
Biteasy.com reports [the same result as well](https://www.biteasy.com/blockchain/transactions/3a0c283c8574205c2cc95cea0e603bfff9087af2ab0360ebd2e98740a3193a18).

Are you sure you are running the latest bitcoind?

Comment: this is alarming. I edited my original post to include my output. What version of bitcoind are you running? From running the "getinfo" RPC command I see that I'm running version 90100, with protocol version 70002.

Comment: Hm, I am running an older version than you on the machine I tried this. I will re-check on a more latest bitcoind.